# JExcel 7 pro - European currency format not working (use comma as decimal separator)

Tags: javascript, number-formatting, jexceljs

I'm trying to display numeric values using the European currency format but it's not working properly. The displayed values are different than the expected due to a format issue.

I'm using the following column configuration:

```
{ type: 'number', title:'Price', mask:'$ #.##,00', decimal:',' }
```

An example of row data:

```
['Jazz', 'Honda', '2019-02-12', '', true, '2000.00', '#777700']
```

The value '2000.00' is formatted as '$ 200.000', but it is expected to be '$ 2.000,00'

You can see the error on the jexcel official web site: https://jexcel.net/v7/examples/column-types

Note: I cannot use the updateTable function to format the values programatically, because it adds performance issues when working with large volume of data.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you use the most recent jSuites version. Then update your mask to:

```
{ type: 'number', title:'Price', mask:'$ #.##0,00', decimal:',' }
```